# Connect AD / DC to public domain

Tags: domain-name-system, domain-controller

I've set up a DC / AC in my home network. Ich also own a domain. So I want to connect the local DC / AC to my Domain, to login from everywhere to my network. 
I tried anything, but still no login servers available, when I try to connect fom outside.
Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I'm confused. Active Directory is an internal authentication mechanism for corporate networks. What exactly do you want to do? And what do you mean by DC / AC? What do you think they stand for?

Comment: I'd get [AC/DC](http://www.acdc.com/) home too, if I only had enough money & room for the audience. :)

Comment: I want to connect from outside my network from mydomain.com to my local Network. I made my IP to go to my Servers Public IP 4v adress. so my IP is just a forwarting to my PC. And now I tried to connect.

Answer (score 2):

The best you can do is to create a subdomain like ad.example.com, and then point the record to the external IP of your DC. You then need to create a domain named ad.example.com on your domain controller.

AD uses DNS for many things, like finding login servers. So you need to point the subdomain to your domain controller. However, clients also need to use the domain controller as DNS server within ad.example.com. To do this, you have to configure the DNS of example.com that it should forward queries to ad.example.com to your DC.

Finally, you have to open all ports AD uses to the internet. That is DNS, Kerberos, and [a handful others](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772723(v=ws.10).aspx).

This is insecure and AD is not made for this. See this excellent question: [Should I expose my Active Directory to the public Internet for remote users?](https://serverfault.com/questions/573681/should-i-expose-my-active-directory-to-the-public-internet-for-remote-users)

Comment: I pointed my subdomain to Thema external IP. After that, I cant follow you. Can you explain it a little bit more detailled pls?
Thanks

Comment: I added some more information. Frankly, this is a bad idea, consider just using a VPN.